# Preventing the user from entering more than specified number of elements in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

How would I go about checking that the user entered the correct number of elements they specified? I would dynamically allocate an array of the `n` elements the user wants, but how would I prevent them from entering more than those `n` elements?

I tried creating a variable called `int num_Elements` and incrementing it in the for loop along the `scanf("%d", &array[i])` every time the user enters an element then checking by `if(num_Elements > length)` (`length` is number of elements user wants), but it didn't work. Or maybe I didn't implement it correctly. Anyone?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int elements = 0;
    int length;
    int i;
    int *p;

    printf("Please enter the number of elements in your array: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    p = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    if (p == NULL) {
        puts("Could not allocate memory");
    } else {
        printf("Enter the %d elements: ", length);
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &p[i]);
            elements++;
            if (elements > length)
                printf("You entered more than\n");
        }
    }

    printf("You entered ");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(p + i));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: They can only enter something if the program asks for it. Don't ask for more than `n` elements.

Comment: Please show your code. Read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) { // code that asks for input }`

Comment: Need more detail than "it didn't work."  Post code, input, output, expected output.

Comment: @HPotter, thanks for adding the code, but you need to explain how it "didn't work". I see no obvious errors, and when I ran your program on my system it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent users from typing more numbers at the prompt than you will read with `scanf()` in the loop. Standard input is line buffered: the characters typed by the user are buffered by the terminal and/or the OS until the user hits the enter key, before `scanf` returns the first time it is called inside the loop.

You could possibly change the terminal mode to `raw` and deal with input one byte at a time, but it would be quite cumbersome.

Here is a simple alternative: read the input with `fgets()`, parse it with `strtol()` and complain if there more input than needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    char *p;
    int i, length;
    int *array;

    printf("Please enter the number of elements in your array: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    if (array == NULL) {
        puts("Could not allocate memory");
    } else {
        getchar(); // read the pending linefeed
        printf("Enter the %d elements: ", length);
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) {
            for (p = buf, i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                // you should check if a number was actually converted...
                array[i] = strtol(p, &p, 10);
            }
            while (isspace((unsigned char)*p) {
                p++;
            }
            if (*p != '\0') {
                printf("You entered extra data\n");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("You entered ");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```